# Host local resource at runtime with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Is it possible to add resources from the local filesystem at runtime to the ASP.NET Core back-end so that they become accessible via HTTP?

Background: I'm developing an ASP.NET Core app using Blazor. The app should allow the user to load images from the local file system and display them within the app. When simply referencing the chosen image via `<img src="file:///C:/temp/myImage.jpg" />`, the browser blocks the request. Within the developer console, there is an error saying that local resources cannot be loaded due to security restrictions. Now I thought about providing the chosen images via the ASP.NET Core back-end. That would allow me to reference the images via `<img src="http://localhost/myImage.jpg" />`

Comment: You don't need the `file:///` bit, note though - this will point to a file location on the _clients_ disk, not the server. It just so happens, in your case, they are the same disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use the static file feature of ASP.Net Core :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Does this feature necessarily have to be invoked at application startup? Or is it possible to configure it at any time?

Comment: Yes, you can't add a middleware dynamicaly.

Comment: So how would that solve my problem? I want the user to choose the pictures dynamically, so I don't know which path to add to the static file feature

Comment: Develop an api controller returning a file then